# Render existing Qt Widget into SVG

Tags: qt

I have an exisiting Graph displayed as QWidget which I can already save to a bitmap using grab():

```
QPixmap image = grab();
```

Is there a Possibility to save that widget also to .svg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
QSvgGenerator generator;
generator.setFileName(path);
generator.setSize(widget->size());
generator.setViewBox(widget->rect());
generator.setTitle(tr("Your title"));
generator.setDescription(tr("some desscription"));
widget->render(&generator);
```

Comment: Thanks!
Works semi-well… the Generator produces a invalid SVG-File (EOG and Inkscape can not open them. 

Error domain 1 code 64 on line 18 column 6 of […]/Chart.svg: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

I can understand this: Viewing this in a text editor reveals several xml tags.

Comment: Probably this error:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2374?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Comment: [This page](https://blogs.kde.org/2011/01/03/rendering-ui-files-svg) describes a potential workaround for that bug.